# append a new form and submit it when there is text in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

I want to append fill in form when I click a create button, and fill in the input text to append the text in a result div. I want to use a submit input to trigger the completeness of input, and hide the form when text is shown in the result div. However, I found that I cannot show text and hide the form. I want to know why I cannot do that.

Here is the code:

html:

```
 <div id="results">
 <button type="button" id="create-group">Create Group</button>
 </div>
```

javascript:

```
var create = document.getElementById('create-group');
  create.addEventListener('click',function(e){
     addForm();
});

function addForm(){
  var form1 = $('<input type="text" id="form1">');
  var form2 = $('<input type="submit" id="form2">');

  $('#results').append("<div id='allForm'>")
  .append(form1)
  .append(form2)
  .append("</div>");
  createGroup();
}

function createGroup(){
  var form=document.getElementById('allForm');
  form.on('submit',function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var item = $('#form1').val();
  if(item){
    $('#results').append("<ul>")
    .append(item)
    .append("</ul>");
    form.remove();
  }
  else{
    alert("Input a name!");
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed up your code a bit, but here is something that works:

**html:**

```
<button type="button" id="create-group">Create Group</button>

<div id="results">

    <script id="results-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

        <h1>{{someResult}}</h1>

    </script>

</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.4/handlebars.js"></script>

<script src="test.js"></script>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var create = $('#create-group');

create.click(function() {

    addForm();

});

});

function addForm(){

  var form1 = $('<input type="text" id="form1">');
  var form2 = $('<input type="submit" id="form2">');

  $('#results').append("<div id='allForm'>")
  .append(form1)
  .append(form2)
  .append("</div>");
  createGroup();

}

function createGroup(){

  var submit = $('#form2');

  submit.click(function() {

    showResult();

  });

}

function showResult() {

  var source = $("#results-template").html();

  //compile returns a function
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

  //provide an object with values
  var context = {

      someResult: $('#form1').val()
  }

  var html = template(context);
  form1.remove();
  form2.remove();
  $('body').append(html);

}
```

I'm using handlebars.js to grab the value of the input, hide the form, and display it into the results div. It might not be the most necessary tool to do that, but I thought it might be useful.

Here is a working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/mtun4g6p/1/